# How to join object values without a loop?

Tags: javascript, object, join

Let's say I have a very simple object...

```
{
  a:"apple",
  b:"banana",
  c:"cherry"
}
```

And I would like to have an output like

```
"apple,banana,cherry"
```

Is there a succinct (without loop) way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

In sufficiently-modern browsers, yes:

```js
var o = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "cherry"
};

var a = Object.keys(o).map(function(el) {
  return o[el];
}).join(",");

console.log(a); // "apple,banana,cherry"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**ECMA 2016+ (?)**

```
Object.values(fruit).join(','); //"apple,banana,cherry"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use .map():

```
var data = {
    a:"apple",
    b:"banana",
    c:"cherry"
}

var dat = $.map(data, function(v){
    return v;
}).join(',');

console.log(dat);
```

Comment: Why would you use `$.map`?

Comment: OP didn't mention jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In properly configured transpilation environments, yes:

```
[ for (k of Object.keys(o)) o[k] ] + ''
```